# If $a_n \ge 0$ and $a_n \to 0$, then $\sum a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, summation, cauchy-sequences, fake-proofs

> If $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$ and $a_n \to 0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges

I recently answered a question different from this one, but found that my methodology could be used to prove the above result, which I know to be untrue (for example, take the harmonic sum). I'm just wondering where exactly my proof fails:

Checking the Cauchy Criterion for the sum:

$$|\sum_{n = 1}^k a_n - \sum_{n=1}^m a_n| = |\sum_{n=m}^k a_n| \le \sum_{n=m}^k |a_n|$$

utilizing the triangle inequality and arbitrarily letting $k > m$.

Since $a_n \to 0$, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ such that $n > N \implies |a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{k - m + 1}$ for any integers $k, m$ with $k > m$. Let $k, m > N$. Then,

$$\sum_{n=m}^k |a_n| < \epsilon$$

So that by the Cauchy criterion, the sum converges.

---

The logic here seems pretty good to me, honestly. I'm assuming that it fails by defining $|a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{k-m+1}$ because we assume $k, m$ to be constants in this definition, yet in the Cauchy criterion for the sum, they are variable.

hence, saying $|a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{k-m+1}$ allows $\sum_{n=m}^r |a_n| < \epsilon$ only for $r \le k$, so that we cannot in general say it holds *for all* values $k, m > N$.

Is this the correct rationale? Could someone shed some (more intuitive) light on it if so, because the rationale I have provided is still a little bothersome to be, for it really is true that $|a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{k-m+1}$ for any choice in $k, m > N$ with $k > m$, so it almost seems as though $k, m$ being variable would be okay.

Comment: The claim that begins with "since $\;a_n\to0,\;$ ..." is completely false.

Comment: @DonAntonio: How so? I just used the definition of a convergent sequence.

Comment: No, you didn't. If you had used that definition then you'd have written that for any pair of integers $\;k,m\;$ there exist $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. if $\;n>N\;$ then $\;|a_n|<\frac1{k-m+1}\;$ ...and even this under the serious condition that $\;k-m\neq-1\;$ ...

Comment: it would imply each $a_n=0$ for $n>N.$ to see this, just fix $m>N$ and let $k\to \infty.$

Comment: observe that $k$ and $m$ can be arbitrarily big. Thus you cant write $|a_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{k-m+1}$ because it is not a defined quantity or, in any case, it is bounded by below by zero.

Comment: This would mean my rationale that "by defining $|a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{k-m+1}$, we assume $k, m$ to be constants, yet in the Cauchy criterion for the sum, they are variable." is correct, yes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the quantifiers that are implicit in the statement you are making. What you have is that for all $\epsilon>0$ and all integers $k,m$ with $k>m>0$, there is an $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $|a_n|<\epsilon/(k-m+1)$. Of course, $N$ depends in general on $k,m$ and there is no way to choose it so that you can further require that $k,m$ are arbitrary numbers larger than $N$.

As a piece of advice, it is good to get used to listing all your quantifiers at the beginning of the statements, to avoid confusions such as the one in this case. This is tricky at first, since it is quite common in informal mathematical discourse to have the quantifiers at the end. From context, it is usually clear what we mean, but the practice leads to confusion (as you have experienced here).

Comment: This would mean my rationale that "by defining $|a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{k-m+1}$, we assume $k, m$ to be constants, yet in the Cauchy criterion for the sum, they are variable." is correct, yes?

Comment: Yes, essentially. To say that there is an $n$ such that $|a_n|<p(k,m)$ for all $k,m$ says that the same $n$ works for all $k,m$, while saying that for all $k,m$ there is an $n$ such that $|a_n|<p(k,m)$ says that there is a "function" $n(k,m)$ with $|a_{n(k,m}|<p(k,m)$. Or, as you say, first you fix $k,m$ in the second version and then you proceed to find $n$, while in the first version you first fix $n$ and then let $k,m$ vary.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was fairly easy to see that this result was impossible via counterexample, and I had an idea as to why my proof wouldn't hold up, but was having some trouble putting my finger on it. I believe you've cleared up those issues for me now.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the sentence "Since... " just before your second displayed equation.  You probably understand that your $N$ depends on $\epsilon$, but it also depends on your $k$.  If what you wrote were really true, you would have $|a_n|< \epsilon/(k-m+1)$ for all $k$ sufficiently large, which already implies $a_n= 0$, which is false even in some cases where $\sum a_n$ does converge.